# How do I upload a R dataframe as a CSV file on Azure blob storage?

Tags: r, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to convert a dataframe in R to a CSV file on Azure Blob storage. I  used the [AzureStor](https://github.com/Azure/AzureStor) package, but it doesnt convert the dataframe properly. I expect 16 columns with data but it returns one columns where all the data is randomly split over the rows.

I used the R code below:

```
library(AzureStor)


bl_endp_key <- storage_endpoint("url", key="key")
cont <- storage_container(bl_endp_key, "containername")
csv <- serialize(dataframe, connection = NULL, ascii = TRUE)
con <- rawConnection(csv)
upload_blob(cont, src=con, dest="output.csv")
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to change or give me example code of how you successfully did it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my sample code, it works fine.

```
library(AzureStor)

df <- data.frame(Column1 = c('Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3'),
                 Column2 = c('Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3'))

account_endpoint <- "https://<your account name>.blob.core.windows.net"
account_key <- "<your account key>"
container_name <- "<your container name>"
bl_endp_key <- storage_endpoint(account_endpoint, key=account_key)
cont <- storage_container(bl_endp_key, container_name)
w_con <- textConnection("foo", "w")
write.csv(df, w_con)
r_con <- textConnection(textConnectionValue(w_con))
close(w_con)
upload_blob(cont, src=r_con, dest="df.csv")
close(con)
```

The content of `df.csv` is as below.

```
"","Column1","Column2"
"1","Value 1","Value 1"
"2","Value 2","Value 2"
"3","Value 3","Value 3"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Peter Pan, It helped me.
Can you help me understand this part of the code
`w_con <- textConnection("foo", "w")
write.csv(df, w_con)`
Where is the CSV being created

Comment: Hi Peter Pan, is there any way to upload RData file to blob storage? Thanks a lot!