# Write a csv file from R Notebook in Databricks to Azure blob storage?

Tags: r, databricks, azure-blob-storage

I have a R Notebook created in databricks with some code running in it. The R script creates a csv file that I need to upload to a specific storage account blob container. To access the blob storage I have a SAS (Shared Access Signature) String. I found out an R package 'AzureStor' that connects R to Azure Storage. Is there a specific command I can use to connect to blob storage using this SAS string and write the csv file directly to the container folder? I am new to databricks and trying to automate an upload process to Azure blob storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I known, there are two ways to write a csv file from R Notebook in Databricks to Azure Blob Storage, as below.

1. Please refer to my answer for the other SO thread [How do I upload a R dataframe as a CSV file on Azure blob storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57307893/how-do-i-upload-a-r-dataframe-as-a-csv-file-on-azure-blob-storage/57321234#57321234) to use `AzureStor` installed by `install.packages("data.table")` to write a R dataframe as a csv file into Azure Blob. The sample code is like as below.

   ```
   library(AzureStor)

   df <- data.frame(Column1 = c('Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3'),
                    Column2 = c('Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3'))

   account_endpoint <- "https://<your account name>.blob.core.windows.net"
   account_key <- "<your account key>"
   container_name <- "<your container name>"
   bl_endp_key <- storage_endpoint(account_endpoint, key=account_key)
   cont <- storage_container(bl_endp_key, container_name)
   w_con <- textConnection("foo", "w")
   write.csv(df, w_con)
   r_con <- textConnection(textConnectionValue(w_con))
   close(w_con)
   upload_blob(cont, src=r_con, dest="df.csv")
   close(con)
   ```
2. First, please follow the offical document [`Data > Data Sources > Azure Blob Storage`](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html) to mount a container of Azure Blob Storage to DBFS, then you can try to use the function [`fwrite`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/fwrite.R) of [`data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) to write data to the directory of Azure Blob container mounted. Note: you can try to run Python script by R package `reticulate`, please refer to my answer for the SO thread [Reading csv files from microsoft Azure using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355132/reading-csv-files-from-microsoft-azure-using-r/57387539#57387539) to know how to use it.